# How to make the div over the image

Tags: html, css, position, absolute, floating

```html
 <div style="border-style:solid; margin:auto;">
   <div style="position:absolute;">
     <div style="background:yellow; border-style:dotted; height:300px; width:300px">
       <h3>THIS IS THE BODY, AND HEIGHT WILL BE CHANGED DYNAMICALLY</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <img src="https://www.google.ca/logos/doodles/2016/lunar-new-year-2016-5134827118395392-hp.jpg">
 </div>
 
 <div style="border-style:solid">
   <h2> THIS IS THE FOOTER</h1>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to put a div over the image, how let the floating div to occupy the space, so the footer div will be pushed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you wish to have the yellow div take up only the amount of space of the div behind it (with the Google Doodle)? Or do you want the reverse, that is, you want the footer height to automatically adjust to the yellow div height?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand. Do you mean to make the div containing the image to have a minimum height? You can use the min-height property then as follows:

```
 <div style="border-style:solid; margin:auto;min-height:80%">
   <div style="position:absolute;">
 <div style="background:yellow; border-style:dotted; height:300px; width:300px">
   <h3>THIS IS THE BODY, AND HEIGHT WILL BE CHANGED DYNAMICALLY</h1>
 </div>
   </div>

   <img src="https://www.google.ca/logos/doodles/2016/lunar-new-year-2016-5134827118395392-hp.jpg">
 </div>

 <div style="border-style:solid">
   <h2> THIS IS THE FOOTER</h1>
 </div>
```

-- Edit: If you are looking for some kind of a background-image in a div container you can control you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border-style:solid; margin:auto">
       <div div style="background-image:url('https://www.google.ca/logos/doodles/2016/lunar-new-year-2016-5134827118395392-hp.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" >
             <div style="border-style:dotted; height:400px; width:600px">

             </div>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div style="border-style:solid">
       <h2> THIS IS THE FOOTER</h1>
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the first div has the height of the img, but I want to let first div has the height of the yellow div, so footer can be pushed by the yellow div instead of the image.

Comment: I think what would help you is a background-image of the div as stated here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp. You should test the examples of w3schools, they really help if you are a css beginner. I edited the answer with an example. Next time you should provide some kind of a sketch, so we will be able to understand better, what it is you want to do :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try to explain the question better next time. And thank you for the answer again.